# Can't get HDMI audio to work with NVIDIA gpu on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

I've been having an issue where I can't use the speakers on my monitor which is connected to my laptop through HDMI. The display works perfectly and even the sounds does on windows but on Ubuntu it just shows my inbuilt speakers/headphones as the only available source.

Also, a bit out of context but the max volume of my speakers on ubuntu is way less than on Windows. So if there's a solution to that it would be great.

Laptop Specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ×86_64 
Host: HP Pavilion Power Laptop 15-cb 
Kernel: 5.8.0-55-generic 
Uptime: 2 hours, 36 mins 
Packages: 2042 (dpkg), 14 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1366x768, 1920x1080
DE: GNOME Mutter
Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal
GPU: Intel i5-7300HQ (4) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile 
Меmогу: 3464MiB 7846MiB
```

inxi

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-55-generic 

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[image: Additional Drivers]

[image: Alsamixer]

[Pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIg2w.png)

Comment: Please show `inxi -A` . You might have to install inxi `sudo apt install inxi` . Thanks

Comment: @Raffles edited

Comment: Please look in the Start Menu at "Additional Drivers" and let us know which driver is in use. Post a screenshot into your question. Thanks

Comment: @Raffles Updated!

Comment: Have you tried going back to a previous driver, or perhaps the 465 driver?

Comment: @Raffles I haven't reverted back to a previous driver but just tried the 465 one and its the same. I'm led to believe this is because both the audio devices are using the same intel driver for some reason.

Comment: @Raffles After digging through the internet I was able to find that the error was due to ubuntu automatically applying power control on the sound card and so I was able to get it working by editing the nvidia file in the root.

Comment: @Nanogines if you have solved your problem, please post an answer. Please don't edit the question.

Comment: @Nanogines no, please don't! You can post your own answer describing what you did to solve your problem (the exact steps might be helpful to the next user who comes across this).

Comment: @muru I just realized I could do that. Done!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Installing pulseaudio worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

After digging through the internet I was able to find that the error was due to ubuntu automatically applying power control on the sound card and so I was able to get it working by editing the nvidia rules file in ubuntu bios rules directory. In that file you just need to switch the "auto" setting in the last couple lines to "on".
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-option-for-audio-over-displayport-hdmi/175889/3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my version and hardware are different. Perhaps it can help...

The command nvidia-smi was returning an error.

I've solved that by applying the procedure describe on the section : "Ubuntu Install Nvidia driver using the CLI method # 2 " of https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

And now the sound is ok on ubuntu.

Comment: Hello. This may be an answer but what about later when the link is no longer working? Please include any info that is needed for the answer in the body of the answer.